# Magento 2.3.1 Change store view in controller_action_predispatch event

Tags: event-observer, cache, store-view, magento2.3.1, store-switcher

In my extension, the default storeview is English and I want to set Arabic storeview, only one time when the customer comes first time on my website. I'm using controller_action_predispatch event to check customer comes the first time or not, if not, customer can move to English storeview as well. Following is my piece of code:

> Namespace\Modulename\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="switch_store" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Observer\SwitchStore" shared="false" />
</event>
```

> Namespace\Modulename\Observer\SwitchStore.php

```
protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    if ($this->firstVisit()) { // Customer's first visit logic inside firstVisit() function
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore($target_store)->getId();
        $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeId);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

This code is working fine for the first time, but when the user tries to switch English storeview, he/she would be redirected to the same storeview, that is Arabic. I debugged so many times, but in logs, I'm getting perfect output and not reflecting the change on the frontend. I think this is a cache issue, but not sure. Please let me know if anyone has a solution for this.

Thanks in anticipate.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not a lot we can review without seeing the firstVisit() function. There seems to be a logic error there.